# Tidy data frame: German characters being removed

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, tidytext

I am using the following code to convert a data frame to a tidy data frame:

```
replace_reg <- "https://t.co/[A-Za-z\\d]+|http://[A-Za-z\\d]+|&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|RT|https"
unnest_reg <- "([^A-Za-z_\\d#@']|'(?![A-Za-z_\\d#@]))"
tidy_tweets <- tweets %>% 
filter(!str_detect(text, "^RT")) %>%
mutate(text = str_replace_all(text, replace_reg, "")) %>%
unnest_tokens(word, text, token = "regex", pattern = unnest_reg) %>%
filter(!word %in% custom_stop_words2$word,
     str_detect(word, "[a-zäöüß]"))
```

However, this produces a tidy data frame where German characters üäöß are removed from the newly-created word column, for example, "wählen" becomes two words: "w" and "hlen," and the special character is removed.

I am trying to get a tidy data frame of German words to do text analysis and term frequencies.

Could someone point me in the right direction for how to approach this problem?

Comment: Replace all `A-Za-z` with `[:alpha:]`. Well, `A-Za-z\\d` can be replaced with `[:alnum:]`. Note: this does not always work, so please check on your end.

Comment: if you tokenize with `cleanNLP` package you can use `init_tokenizers(locale = "German)`

Comment: you could also change your [A-Za-z] to a hex range:  http://www.asciitable.com/  and specify all the characters you want to keep.  Along the lines of [^\x20-\x7E]  and just add \x{germanstuff} for the other ones

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, [:alum:] has nearly done the trick! I still have some stray letters that appear as words, but it does not seem related to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace all `A-Za-z\\d` in your bracket expressions with `[:alnum:]`.

The POSIX character class `[:alnum:]` matches Unicode letters and digits.

```
replace_reg <- "https://t.co/[[:alnum:]]+|http://[[:alnum:]]+|&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|RT|https"
unnest_reg <- "([^[:alnum:]_#@']|'(?![[:alnum:]_#@]))"
```

If you are using these pattern with *stringr* functions, you may also consider using `[\\p{L}\\p{N}]` instead, like in

```
unnest_reg <- "([^\\p{L}\\p{N}_#@']|'(?![\\p{L}\\p{N}_#@]))"
```

where `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter and `\p{N}` matches any Unicode digit.